# Length angular of items in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First, I have this table:

[image]

Where you can see, different colours in the column estado. There are 4 different cases. And i Want to count this different cases. For example in this case there are: Active(green): 1, Vodafone(green+logo): 1, Desactive(Red): 1, Pending(orange):1. But it can change depend of the case.

```
<div class="input-group">
                      <div>  <h>Instalaciones: {{filteredsites.length}}</h>  <h>Active: {{}}</h> <h>Vodafone: {{}}</h> <h>Desactive: {{}}</h> <h>Pending: {{}}</h></div>

                </div>
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div >
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped dataTable no-footer" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                                <tr role = "row" class="info text-center">
                                    <th ng-click="order('msisdn')">Número Teléfono</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('icc')">ICC</th>

                                    <!--th>IMEI</th-->
                                    <th ng-click="order('ActivationStatus')">Estado</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitename')">Instalación</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('siteaddress')">Dirección</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitecity')">Ciudad</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitezip')">Código Postal</th>

                                    <th ng-click="order('phonedesc')">Modelo Teléfono</th>



                                </tr>


                                <tr class=" text-center" ng-repeat-start="object in filteredsites = (objects | filter:searchText | filter:{parentgroupid:selectedgroup||undefined}) | filter:tableFilter| orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails" >
                                    <td>{{object.msisdn}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.icc}}</td>

                                    <!--td>{{object.ActivationStatus}}</td-->
                                    <td><span ng-init="getStatusCount(object.ActivationStatus)"  ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='AC' && object.ContractingMode=='0'" class="fa fa-square fa-3x"style="color:lime"></span><span ng-show="object.ContractingMode=='2' && object.ActivationStatus=='AC'  "  ><img src="../img/Vodafone_logo.png" width="40" height="40" style="background-color: lime"></span><span ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='PA'"  class="fa fa-square fa-3x"style="color:yellow"></span><span ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='DE'" class="fa fa-square fa-3x"style="color:red"></span></td>
                                    <td>{{object.sitename}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.siteaddress}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.sitecity}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.sitezip}}</td>
                                    <td><span ng-show="object.phonedesc==''"></span><span ng-show="object.phonedesc=='Desconocido'">Desconocido</span><span></span>{{getPhoneModel(object.phonedesc)}}</td>
                                </tr>

                           </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->




                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-4 (nested) -->

                    <!-- /.col-lg-8 (nested) -->
                </div>
```

And the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboard', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('dashboardController', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {
    $scope.objects = [];
    $scope.grupos = [];
    $scope.longitud = [];
    $scope.eventos = [];



    var URL = "/api/auth/logout";
    var URLOperation = "/api/sites";
    var URLModel = "http://localhost:81/api/phonelist/";
$scope.getStatusCount= function (status){
   // console.log(status);

    var active = 0;
    active++;
    console.log(active);
    angular.forEach(status ,function(obj) {
        if (obj.status == status) {
            console.log(obj.status);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(active);
            active++;
            console.log(active);
        } });


}


//Funci?n que devuelve las instalaciones de un usuario
    $http.get(URLOperation, $scope)
            .success(function (data) {
                var groups = data;
                angular.forEach(groups, function (group) {
                    var group2 = group;
                    angular.forEach(group2.sites, function (group3) {
                        $scope.longitud.push(group3);
                        $scope.objects.push(group3);
                        $scope.predicate = 'msisdn';
                        $scope.reverse = true;
                        $scope.order = function (predicate) {
                            $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
                            $scope.predicate = predicate;
                        };
                    })
                });
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                window.alert('Something Wrong...');
            });




});
```

If someone can help me the count the different ActivationStatus cases i will appreciated.

Comment: Which element length you want and in which scope? Please elaborate it

Comment: i want the lenght of the object.ActivationStatus and object.ContractingMode but it have to meet the conditions that i put.

Comment: means in object.ActivationStatus and object.ContractingMode, you want length of 'object ' ? Where you want access this length in your code?

Comment: You can just use `object.ActivationStatus.length` and `object.ContractingMode.length`

Comment: i put an example. I have 3 objects with AC and two with Contracting mode 0 and the other with contracting mode 2. I want the length of this: Active-Yes: 2 and Active-No: 1

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but can't you just do: ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='AC' && (object.ContractingMode=='0' || object.ContractingMode=='2')

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much had it correct? I worked on your `example` in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iElykNoIG8KY8d3yrDVC?p=preview) and it worked right off the bet?

```
ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='AC' && object.ContractingMode=='0'"
```

Seemed to be working for me.

Comment: Yes this works but i want the lenght of the different ng-show in this case have to show one and the same if the contracting mode is 2

Comment: <div class="input-group">
                        <div>
                        <h>Instalaciones: {{filteredsites.length}}</h>  <h>Activas: {{ }}</h> <h>VBP: {{}}</h></div>


                    </div>

Comment: You mean you want a calculated field?

Comment: I think I know what you ment... check the updated plunker and tell me if this is heading in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, is this. But the problem is how to differenciate the contracting mode of the status AC for do two different counts.

Comment: Could you reformulate that? I did not understand your question to be honest. You want to count the AC per modus? So AC +0 = 1 and AC + 2 = 1 in the example?

Comment: More or less! What are the conditions of the four cases?

Comment: For active ActivationStatus='AC', Pending: ActivationStatus='PA', Desactive: ActivationStatus='DE', Vodafone: ContractingMode='2'